# My css animation for header is not working?

Tags: css

my header is expanding downward. but how can I animate this to take 1 second from top to bottom?
I did add one but its not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/MrWhestr/5xLmdy4h/

HTML

```
<div class="momnav" id ="mymomnav">
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">ANA SAYFA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">HAKKIMIZDA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">İLETİŞİM</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.momnavresponsive   {
    display: flex;
    transition: height 1s ;

}
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {


var x = document.getElementById("mymomnav");
if ( x.className === "momnav") {
    x.className += "responsive";
}

else {
    x.className = "momnav";
}
}
```

Comment: Look into this: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

Comment: Solutions look good. I'll take a quick look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by CSS `transition`. `transition` doesn't work for values that cannot be represented numerically: `auto`, `display: none/block/flex etc` etc.

For exmaple,

- ❌`height: 0` <-> `height: auto`
- ❌`display: none` <-> `display: flex`
- ✅`height: 0` <-> `height: 100vh`
- ✅`color: blue` <-> `color: red` (Colors CAN be reperesented numerically)

---

#### Here is your problematic code:

```
.momnav {
  display: none; /* NOT work for none <-> flex */
}

.momnavresponsive   {
  display: flex; /* NOT work for none <-> flex */
  transition: height 1s; /* NOT work for 0 <-> auto */
}
```

You have to write more CSS/JavaScript for a dropdown menu.

---

#### Here is one of the easiest solution:

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('#menu-btn');
const classToAssign = 'is-open-menu';

function toggleMenu(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  // When <body> has .is-open-menu class
  if (body.classList.contains(classToAssign)) {
    // Remove the class = close the menu
    body.classList.remove(classToAssign);
  }
  // When <body> DOES NOT have .is-open-menu class
  else {
    // Add the class = open the menu
    body.classList.add(classToAssign);
  }
}

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu, false);
```

```css
/* Skip this part and see below */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  padding: 2em;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.header-top__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

/* CHECK THIS */
/* Closed menu */
.menu {
  height: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.menu__inner {
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background-color: tomato;
}

/* CHECK THIS */
/* Opened menu */
.is-open-menu .menu {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.is-open-menu .menu__inner {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="header" class="header">
    <div class="header-top">
      <div class="header-top__inner wrap">
        <h1 class="site-logo"><a href="#">Website Name</a></h1>
        <button id="menu-btn" class="menu-btn"></button><!-- CHECK -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="menu"><!-- CHECK -->
      <div class="menu__inner wrap"><!-- CHECK -->
        <ul class="menu-list">
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main class="main">
    <div class="wrap">
      <p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Go to Google</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit neque doloribus quo voluptatibus accusamus commodi blanditiis cupiditate asperiores iusto est. Sunt iste, corporis non saepe quis consectetur natus necessitatibus tempore.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit neque doloribus quo voluptatibus accusamus commodi blanditiis cupiditate asperiores iusto est. Sunt iste, corporis non saepe quis consectetur natus necessitatibus tempore.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit neque doloribus quo voluptatibus accusamus commodi blanditiis cupiditate asperiores iusto est. Sunt iste, corporis non saepe quis consectetur natus necessitatibus tempore.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit neque doloribus quo voluptatibus accusamus commodi blanditiis cupiditate asperiores iusto est. Sunt iste, corporis non saepe quis consectetur natus necessitatibus tempore.</p>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: While I think this is fine for a nav, keep in mind that scaling doesn't affect content around it. Also, a slightly _cleaner_ way of doing this to avoid the ugly content skewing is to scale the container first and then fade in the content (inverse for retracting).

Comment: Thank you for your advice :) I know this is not a great way. But I think it's relatively understandable for beginners. If you have any other recommended way, I'd appreciate it if you could post it :)

Comment: I linked an article on OP that covers the case you posted as well as 3 others.

Short answer:
If dropdown is static, just use set an explicit height.
If drowdown is dynamic, use js.

Comment: Thanks. I got it now. I solve the problem in there https://jsfiddle.net/MrWhestr/5xLmdy4h/3/. But how ı do it affect content around it with CSS or ı should use js like GHOST-34 says?

Comment: Check my CSS in there: https://jsfiddle.net/ah7wqnLv/7/ . By the way, I recommend my JS. Your JS changes the class name, so you need to write the same CSS in the two classes: `transition-property: height, opacity; transition-delay: 0, 0.5s; transition-duration: 1s; overflow: hidden;`. It's a little inefficient.

Comment: My solution is not suitable for a list that has multiple dropdown items such as FAQ page. But it's ok for a header nav. You can stick to it. Of course GHOST-34's suggestion is probably better. If you code more professionally, give it a try :)

Comment: Thank you all. When I learn new things, people like you increase my motivation :)